# Issue with popping UIViewController from UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing a static library for user authentication on iOS.

On Click of a button, the developer will call the method of my library and pass the current reference of `UINavigationController` like this:

```
LoginViewController *LoginView = [LoginViewController alloc]init];
[LoginView ShowLoginScreen : self.navigationController];
```

In `ShowLoginScreen:pRootNavController` method I am creating a new `UIViewController` with a cancel button and adding it to `navigationController` like this:

```
LoginViewController * loginscreen = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.vRootNavController = pRootNavController 
// provide a funnction here eg ShowLoginScreen( self.navigationController )
[self.vRootNavController pushViewController:loginscreen animated:YES];
[self.vRootNavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.vRootNavController.viewControllers];
int size = [navigationArray count];
NSLog(@"No of view controllers are %d",size);
```

This is logging `No of view controllers are 2`.

On Click of `Cancel` Button, I want to pop the current `UIViewController` from the `self.vRootNavController`. In the event handler of `Cancel` button I am doing this:

```
[self.vRootNavController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

SMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.vRootNavController.viewControllers];    
int size = [navigationArray count];
NSLog(@"No of view controllers are %d",size);
```

The issue is that on tapping the `Cancel` button the current `UIViewController` is not getting removed and it is logging that `No of view controllers are 0`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you calling 'LoginViewController * loginscreen = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];'
You are initializing LoginViewController twice

Comment: Hhow can I push the `LoginViewController` on the `vRootNavController` without initializing it ?

Comment: You can't. But in an already initialized controller, you are creating ANOTHER instance of LoginViewController. Is that what you really want? Can't you just add Cancel button to an existing instance?